# Analysing exe file https connections

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark

I have a exe file, which is sending an https request to the remote server and I think, is downloading something from the site. With process hacker 2 I've got only the remote IP, but I need to see get or post parameters too. Wireshark is seeing the sent request, but all data is encrypted by SSL. It looks like that - https://prnt.sc/sft9a6
Is there any way to decrypt SSL traffic?

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS you can probably start from there or https://www.google.com/search?&q=wireshark+ssl What have you found and tried so far? Where are you stuck? What problems have you met?

Comment: @Mokubai I have added the environment variable for SSL certificate sniffing, but the file remains empty. So I can't really do anything with those. https://prnt.sc/sftpwl

Answer (score 1):

Try running the traffic from the exe file through a TLS proxy to inspect the decrypted TLS traffic. You can use [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) (our tool) or [SSLsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit) to generate a PCAP file with the traffic in **decrypted** form. Another option is to run the traffic through [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-wireshark-tls/) and let it export the SSL key material.

Also, setting an SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable variable will probably not be of much help since it is only respected by a handful number of applications, primarily browsers. Most other software will simply continue doing SSL as usual, without logging any keys. This issue is particularly obvious when trying analyze network traffic from malware.

Comment: Is your tool available for windows? I see only links for Linux. And for Windows only some certificate installations

Comment: @Mike2233 We have so far only released Linux builds of PolarProxy. We'd love to release a Windows build as well as, but we haven't found a decent way of redirecting outgoing traffic to the proxy in Windows. The [Windows firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-outbound-port-rule) doesn't allow REDIRECT actions for Outbound Rules (only ALLOW and BLOCK). This limitation defeats the purpose of running the proxy on the Windows machine.

Comment: @mike2233 Update: There is now a Windows build of PolarProxy. We also have macOS builds for x64 and ARM64 (M1/M2).